# How to prefab animations in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

created a prefab for door and added the prefab doors to the scene. This prefab door has an animator. The problem is when I try to change the animator x,y,z position on the second door in the scene it changes the first door.

I tried duplicating the doors and changing the position x y z but it changed the animator for the first door.

I just have a script that play the animator.

The expected result should be that I can drag and drop doors as needed without creating individual animators for each door. It looks like i need to create animators per door there is and also this probably will require me to create new scripts per each door. It seems awkward since I should be able to add doors and just chaning the position x y z in the animator.

Comment: All are working together ? - so that is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that their `Animator` component uses the same `AnimatorController` asset which uses certain `AnimationClip` asset references for it's states.

I don't know if there is an easier way for achieve but I would do the following:

- For what you want you would have to copy the `AnimatorController` asset (CTRL+D) as well as the `AnimationClip` asset you want to change.
- Then in the cloned `AnimatorController` click on the according State you want to change and in the Inspector reference the according cloned `AnimationClip`.
- Now you have a copy of the `AnimatorController` using a different `AnimationClip` but with the same states, traditions etc. so you can edit both animations and controllers individually.
- finally in the `Animator` component reference the according `AnimatorController` for each prefab.

The remaining problem maybe is now that for the future if you change the States, transitions and especially parameters you have to do it in both `AnimatorController` assets individually.

Comment: I understand. Wow I just cant believe that something so common dont have an easy fix. I also thought of in my script have the name of the animator match the name of the gameobject and then I just need to create an animator for each door the animator would be like doorOpendoor1 doorOpendoor2 etc. Concatenating the names I won't have a problem of conflicting animators. What you think?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question. As said the core elements are not the `Animator` but rather the `AnimatorController`s and `AnimationClip`s. Yes I usually call them according to the objects name I to not confuse them and pack all specific animation clips into one equal named folder ;) you know however that you only need it if you want different behaviours for those doors. If the main reason for you changing all of them actually is just different position and rotation innthe world rather give them a parent object and position/rotate that one instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is perhaps not because of an animator, but a specific behavior of animation in Unity. Animation animates transform property according to parent, as far as I understand. So the first parent of your prefab is captured, and its transform property is used for animation. But I'm not exactly sure about this explanation - the actual behavior is covered under the Unity's source code. A common solution for this that I found is to create a parent or container inside your object's prefab. I don't know why it works, but it works. Perhaps because the parent of your animated object is now always the same.

Parent can be just an empty game object. So you make your door prefab, place another empty game object into this prefab, make your door a child of this container, set 0 for all coordinates of your door according to container and for the container itself. Now you can add an animator component to your object, which you want to animate (not the container), and animate it inside the prefab scene. After that you can place the copies of this prefab (container + your animated object inside) wherever you want inside your game scene - all animations of copies will proceed independently.